# Unity Android application in-app browser ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, url

I have recently published an application on the play store that allows users to sign up for events hosted for youths in a local mosque. These events are managed by a group through a back-end application that enables them to create and manage events as well as activating an event that people can sign up for.

During the sign-up the user has the option to pay online or cash. When the user chooses to pay online, he or she is redirected to a payment link through a plugin called 'In-app browser' in the asset store. This was really helpful, because it also allowed me to use javascript and callbacks. I am using this functionality to continuously check the current URL to see if the URL matches the URL of the page when the user has completed the transaction. The browser automatically closes and completes the sign-up when that is the case.

The problem currently resides in the payment part. The user can choose his or her bank to proceed to an iDeal payment. This results in a 'ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME' error as shown in the picture. I have tried adding the the URI to the manifest as shown in the code below. I don't have much experience with Android development, so I am a bit clueless on this topic. I have also tried following [this](http://oferei.com/2013/06/serverless-instagram-authentication/) guide, but this results in the same problem. I am not sure how to make this applicable for my application.

I have seen several issues with the same error, but this is mostly in native android development instead of Unity and I am also using an asset as a browser, so I haven't found a solution that matches this scenario.

```
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.google.firebase.unity"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="bunq" />
    <data android:host="app" />  cover all your bases 
    <data android:host="app.open" />
</intent-filter>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
</manifest>`
```

[image: URI Scheme error]

Comment: `I am using this functionality to continuously check the current URL to see if the URL matches the URL of the page when the user has completed the transaction.` could you add those `URL`s to your question please? Since the Exception is related to the URL format that would be helpful I guess. The issue might already be the `bunq://`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

I took this from an earlier debug session with adb logcat:

InAppBrowser: FinishedLoading With Error bunq://x-bunq-app/token-qr-bunqme-fundraiser-profile-entry?token=5df9b16cbfdfc0a3ef1c13bdd52db6946b7ccfb83ab402ab7e81cd46b796af84,net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: I ment you should add the URLs you actually call in Unity not only the one reaching on the server

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.The initial URL is https://www.bunq.me/mja. The user then chooses his bank to proceed with the payment. One of the options is the bank 'bunq'. Choosing this results in the error I have shown in the comment above. When I choose the bank I use and proceed with the payment, the URL is ' https://www.abnamro.nl/portalserver/nl/.../...'.  This doesn't result in an error, even when the transaction is completed. The URL of a successful transaction is: https://bunq.me/i?trxid=0.... This results in a trigger in the application to close the browser and complete the transaction